# Mark all as read button for recycler view android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hi I'm wondering how to mark all items as read on button click in recyclerview android

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a boolean variable in your Model class
2. when someone click the recycle item you can change the value
   of boolean and mark it as read